# What css framework should I use if I just want to make my website responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-frameworks

So basically my website works fine, I want to keep all the colors,fonts, etc just the way they are. So  what I just want is to make my website responsive for mobile and tablet. I've been looking at Base and Gumby, not sure if those are good choices because I've never worked on them. So basically do I just install the grid system when I want to do something like this ? What's the best framework to use for something like that's not gonna mess with my padding and other stuff that I already have on my website. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly duplicate of How to ask question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The non-opinion-based, objective bit**

Installing most grid systems on top of your website will likely break some aspects of it. You can't really just plop one in and just use it when you need it, you need to start the design with it and carry it all the way through.

If you want to make it responsive without having to rewrite from scratch, look into [media queries](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en), because that's the magic of it.

A CSS framework uses a lot of media queries for the responsive design bit, then bundles **lots** of stuff on top of it. If you just want the responsive side of things, you can implement your own media queries (common breakpoints are 0-640px for mobile, 641-1024px for tablet and 1025px+ for desktop.

---

**The bit that can get opinion-based if you're not careful (but hopefully isn't, here)**

There are a lot of popular frameworks for responsive design (and the whole mcguffins that goes along with them), with two of the most popular ones being Twitter Bootstrap and Zurb Foundation. I'm not promoting discussion of them here, because SO isn't for opinions, I'm just saying that they exist and are widely considered "robust enough" for production work if you want to go look at them. There are many others which are also robust enough.

Comment: thank you much! I ended up not using Bootstrap which I already started, but I will not use it now. I am currently working on media queries...I appreciate it!